# Update ng-model or $scope variables from controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I am having some difficulties in updating textbox using Angularjs with ASP.Net MVC. I have `<div>` tag displaying `ng-model`... When I click on Edit button, a textbox appears so I can edit the name that was displayed in the `<div>`...

I am using different ng-models in the `div` and the `input` because I don't want direct binding...

So, I am actually having two questions:

1- If I will use the same `ng-model` in both sides, what if I wanted to cancel editing after entering text already?? The text will be changed anyway, is there a way to undo the change??

2- If not, then my second question, I need your help in updating the textbox `input` to get the value of the `div` when I click on Edit.

Below is my code:

My view:

```
<div ng-show="!nameElements" class="item_list">{{u.fName}}</div>
<div ng-show="nameElements">
     <input type="text" id="ufn" ng-model="userfName">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="updateUserName()"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

My angular controller:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetUser')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
        $scope.itmNo = response.length;
        $scope.userfName = response[0].fName;//This is not working!!
        }
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

So, the issue is, I am not able to change/update the ng-model from my controller.

I hope my question is clear

Comment: What do you expect `response[0].fName` to be? `response` is an object with properties `data`, `status`, `headers`, `config`, and `statusText`. It is not an array.

Comment: I wanted to get the fName field from the database. It is working from my view using `n in users` and then `n.fName`... But I don't know how I can get it in the controller.... The general idea is to set the `input` value equals to the `fName` that displayed in the `div`

Comment: It seems that my issue is with `response[0].fName`... Can you please help me on how I can represent individual field in my controller? It was fine when I was using `.success` with `$http.get`

Comment: $scope.userfName = response[0].fName;//This is not working!! 

This should be:
$scope.userfName = response.data[0].fName;

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me likely that you were previously using `.success(function (response) {...})` and changed it to `.then(function(response) {...}`.

The parameters for `.success()` and `.then()` callbacks are not the same. The first parameter passed to the `.success()` calback is the `response.data` value passed to `.then()`.

Your code should probably be:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetUser')
    .then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data
        $scope.users = data.data;
        $scope.itmNo = data.length;
        $scope.userfName = data[0].fName;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happened to me. Thank you very much... I have another question though! Is there any way in angular to undo change or reset input field? Let's say it was written 'Hello' and I have changed it into 'Hi', I want a button that reset the value to the default which is 'Hello'... Thanks

Comment: If the hello is not a placeholder but really a value you can just make a reset button that have a ng-click to a reset function that is setting your scope object to the hello value

Comment: Understood, but I still have one issue... I have created `ng-click` that calls a function to reset the `input`, but `data[0].fName` is not recognized out of `.then`? Any advice??

Comment: Because when I reset the `input`, I want it to get the `data[0].fName` as default value

Comment: You have the value in $scope.userfName if that is already overwritten by the input because the model is in that you can make a variable in the controller saying defaultFName. SO you get $scope.userfName = data[0].fName and on next line defaultfName = data[0].fName. In the reset function you can do $scope.userfName = defaultfName;